# JavaScript window.location.search.substr(1) returns as an empty string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to retrieve the GET parameters from a webpage using JavaScript but it's returning an empty string.

This is my form:

```
<form onsubmit="fn()" action='test.php' method='GET'>
<input type='text' name='word'>
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```

And this is my JS:

```
var word;
function fn(){
    word = window.location.search.substr(1);
    console.log(word);
}
```

The console returns: [" "] and the form is in the same file as the JS.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the URL you are running it on? If it doesn't have a question mark with text after it, it should be empty.

Comment: http://localhost/test.php?word=i

Comment: Is that the URL before you submit the form? If so, it should be working.

Comment: no it's the one after. the one before is: localhost/test.php

Comment: it's the same page

Comment: Right, so what I said before holds true. `window.location.search` refers to the part of the URL after, and including, the question mark. A form's `onsubmit` handler runs *before* the URL is changed. If you just want to get the value of the `word` text box, just use `document.querySelector('[name="word"]').value`.

Comment: Thanks! where should I put the document.querySelector('[name="word"]') ?

Comment: Honestly, you should just learn more about how HTML & JavaScript works together (you should be able to find plenty of tutorials online), then come back once you start understanding more.

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns the parameters for the current page.

What happens is this:
You enter some data in your input and push the submit button.
The javascript function runs, still on same page/url.
Then after that the browser does a GET request with ?word=someData

What are you trying to achieve?